# JDBC for user authentication not working with gui, blocking access even when correct username and password is enetered

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've set up a Gui and a JBDC. I have listed in my tables a username : admin and password : admin and when I input these into the gui login it is still locking me out and im unsure why its locking me out... Below is my code

```
 public class Login extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jtfUsername, jtfPassword;
    private JButton backButton, loginButton;
    private JMenuItem jmiLogin, jmiBack, jmiHelp, jmiAbout;

    Login() {
        //create menu bar
        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();

        //set menu bar to the applet
        setJMenuBar(jmb);

        //add menu "operation" to menu bar
        JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Options");
        optionsMenu.setMnemonic('O');
        jmb.add(optionsMenu);

        //add menu "help"
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        helpMenu.setMnemonic('H');
        helpMenu.add(jmiAbout = new JMenuItem("About", 'A'));
        jmb.add(helpMenu);

        //add menu items with mnemonics to menu "options"
        optionsMenu.add(jmiLogin = new JMenuItem("Login", 'L'));
        optionsMenu.addSeparator();
        optionsMenu.add(jmiBack = new JMenuItem("Back", 'B'));

        //panel p1 to holds text fields
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        p1.add(jtfUsername = new JTextField(15));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        p1.add(jtfPassword = new JPasswordField(15));

        //panel p2 to holds buttons
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        p2.add(backButton = new JButton("Back"));
        p2.add(loginButton = new JButton("Login"));

        //Panel with image??????

        //add panels to frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        panel.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setTitle("Main Page");


        //listners for exit menuitem and button
        jmiBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
                welcome.setVisible(true);
                welcome.setSize(500, 500);
                welcome.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        //listner for about menuitem
        jmiAbout.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "This is the login panel"
                        + "\n Assignment for University",
                        "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        //action listeners for Login in button and menu item
        loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
    boolean loggedIn = usernamecheck.checkLogin(jtfUsername.getText(), jtfPassword.getText());
    if (!loggedIn) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry, wrong credentials"); 
        //displayErrorMessage("Sorry, wrong credentials");
        return;
    }
}
                
catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Sorry, couldn't check your credentials. Check the logs and report the problem to an administrator.");
    return;
}
                
                MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                mainmenu.setSize(500, 500);
                mainmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        jmiLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
                mainmenu.setVisible(true);
                mainmenu.setSize(500, 500);
                mainmenu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                registerInterface regFace = new registerInterface();
                regFace.setVisible(false);
                Login.this.dispose();
                Login.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Login frame = new Login();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class usernamecheck {

    static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "root";


   // launch the application
    public static boolean checkLogin(String username, String password)
            throws SQLException {
        System.out.print("Running Check Login \n");

        Connection connection = null; // manages connection
        PreparedStatement pt = null; // manages prepared statement
        Statement stmt = null;
        String query="select userName from person where userName = ? and password = ?";


        // connect to database usernames and query database
        try {

            // establish connection to database
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "root", "root");

            // query database
            pt = con.prepareStatement("select userName from person where userName = ? and password = ?");
           
            // process query results
            pt.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery(query);
            String orgUname = "", orPass = "";
            if (rs.next()) {
                orgUname = rs.getString("userName");
                orPass = rs.getString("password");
            } //end while
            if (rs.next() && password.equals(rs.getString("password")) && username.equals(rs.getString("userName"))) {
                //do something
                return true;
            } else {
                //do something
                return false;
            }
        }//end try
        catch (Exception e) {
        } //end catch  
        return false;
    } //end main
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any exception or stacktrace in your console?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
        } //end catch 
        finally {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }` I've added stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

In your `checkLogin(String username, String password)` method,
 you set username for `PreparedStatement` as parameter but you forgot to set `password`

```
           // query database
            pt = con.prepareStatement("select userName from person where userName = ? and password = ?");

            // process query results
            pt.setString(1, username);
            ??
```

Comment: It seems like that,did you try that